# Tumblr theming - show preview image for "link" post type?

Tags: tumblr

When you add a "link" type post to Tumblr:

[image: link]

...your admin shows a small thumbnail of any image associated with that link:

[image: admin]

However, this doesn't show on the frontend of the site:

[image: frontend]

Is there any way to pull this image through?

Comment: If you use [pytumblr](https://pypi.org/project/PyTumblr/) when you call the `create_link` method you can add the parameter `thumbnail={image-url}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Tumblr Link Theme Operator and Thumbnail

Tumblr recently added some new theme operators to allow for link thumbnails.

I presume this works the same as video thumbnails work and may only be available if the linked site creates the thumbnail.

```
{block:Link}
{block:Thumbnail}
<img src="{Thumbnail}" alt="{Name}">
{/block:Thumbnail}
{/block:Link}
```

Reference: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#link-posts

Comment: Great thanks! Just to note, there's a missing " after the image source. Other than that works fine.

Comment: @JazzHands My pleasure! Updated the answer with the missing `"`.

Comment: Thanks! I just noticed that on my tumblr blog and fixed it. Only took 4 years :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how it's done:

Click on your blogs name on the dashboard above or in the bloglist on the right hand side.

Click on Customize on the right hand side (or just go to the template you chose)

Once you're in there you can change the HTML on top on the left hand side, right under the templates name and icon

There you look for the 
`{block:Link}` and before the description you add:
`{block:Thumbnail}`
`<img src="{Thumbnail}" alt="{Name}">`
{/block:Thumbnail}`