# How to make page content show up in Tumblr link posts?

Tags: tumblr

I have a page with some photos and text. When I post a URL of that page in a Tumblr "Link" post, it shows nothing.

What do I need to do to make my page display content when its URL is inserted into Tumblr "Link" post?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#link-posts

Comment: @mikedidthis thanks

Comment: @mikedidthis: Isn’t this what `{Thumbnail}`, `{Excerpt}` etc. are for (ref. [*Tumblr theming - show preview image for “link” post type?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22530756/1591669)), and OP wants to know how Tumblr can detect this information on his external site?

Comment: I've found out actually. It's meta tags in the `<head>` of the html that are responsible for this. Especially `<meta property="og:image"`

Comment: @unor It seems the OP wants to render the content of the page being linked to, ala `<iframe/>`. The `{Thumbnail}` is a thumbnail grabbed from the meta data from the page being linked to. The `{Excerpt}` is taken from the Post Link content, it is not the content of the page being linked to.